# Is it possible to run fluentd as a AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, fluent, fluentd

I have logs in data lake. I want to parse and push those logs AWS S3 using fluent-s3 output plugin. Here i want to run fluentd as a AWS lambda which it will trigger and push the data lake files into S3. Is it possible to to run fluentd as a AWS Lambda. To run Fluentd as a lambda what are the steps i need to follow?

Comment: I doubt you can run fluentd within AWS lambda, but I'm not sure it even makes sense to consider doing this. Why do you think Lambda would help you here, and what would trigger the Lambda function?

Comment: I want to push parsing logs from data lake which is in file to AWS S3 bucket using S3 output plugin. If i trigger Fluentd as lambda function, it will push each file at time.

Comment: I'm assuming that the data lake is not actually in S3 so when files are added to the data lake, it does not generate a Lambda event. If that's correct then you'd have to artificially generate Lambda events when files are added to the data lake and if you're doing that then why not simply process the log files normally outside of Lambda?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. Data lake is nothing but S3. logs are pushed into S3 bucket in a file with out parsing. Here I need to parse logs and again store into S3 using S3 output plugin. If i used fluentd as Lambda function, no need to think about scaling and performance. If i got 100 files in S3, 100 lambda will invoke and parse those files. How can i create fluentd as a lambda?

Comment: Run Fluentd as container using ECS